Nowhere continuous marginal density
This is based on Exercise 4.5.1 in Grimmett & Stirzaker. Let
$$ f(x,y)=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{8\pi}}\exp \left(-|x|^2-\frac{1}{2}x^2 y^2 \right) $$
First, we show that this is a continuous joint density but the marginal density $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x, y)dy$ is discontinuous at $x=0$. Next, we let $Q=\{q_n : n\geq N\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and define
$$ f_Q(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n f(x-q_n, y) $$
We can show the same for $f_Q(x,y)$, namely that it is a continuous joint density and that $Q$ is the set of discontinuities of the marginal density $f_Q(x)$.
Finally, the exercise asks to construct a continuous joint density whose first marginal density is nowhere continuous. I reasoned correctly that we can just take $Q=\mathbb{Q}$, the set of rational numbers.
However, this left me wondering -- since it is a density, the distribution function is equal to its integral. But how can a function which is discontinuous everywhere be integrable? I don't know measure theory well enough so would appreciate an example of such a function which is Riemann-integrable. I know that one can Riemann-integrate bounded functions with finitely many discontinuities, and I also know that one can Riemann-integrate bounded functions whose set of discontinuities is the Cantor set (i.e., it is uncountable). The textbook has also been exclusively using Riemann integrals so far.

A map is Riemann integrable iff it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere (see here), so it's not possible to give an example like the one you want. It is possible for such a map to be Lebesgue integrable, though (a standard example is the indicator function of the rationals, which is not Riemann integrable but has Lebesgue integral $0$).

@stochasticboy321 Thanks for your comment. This is the cause of my confusion. I'm trying to understand what's the main message of this exercise. Is it meant to demonstrate a 'trick' (via the marginalisation of an appropriate joint distribution) to arrive at a random variable whose density function is nowhere continuous?
